# New Noise For Each Epoch

Tags: keras, noise

I am building a denoising autoencoder in keras and the code is below:

```python
input_signal = Input(shape=(M,))
encoded = Dense(M, activation='relu')(input_signal)
encoded1 = Dense(n_channel, activation='linear')(encoded)
encoded2 = BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001,center=True, scale=True, beta_initializer='zeros', gamma_initializer='ones', moving_mean_initializer='zeros', moving_variance_initializer='ones', beta_regularizer=None, gamma_regularizer=None, beta_constraint=None, gamma_constraint=max_norm(1.4142136))(encoded1)

EbNo_train = 5.01187 #  coverted 7 db of EbNo 5.01187
noise_std = np.sqrt(1/(2*R*EbNo_train))
encoded3 = Lambda(lambda x: x + K.random_normal(shape=K.shape(encoded2),mean=0.0,stddev=noise_std))(encoded2)

decoded = Dense(M, activation='relu')(encoded3)
decoded1 = Dense(M, activation='softmax')(decoded)
autoencoder = Model(input_signal, decoded1)
adam = Adam(lr=0.003)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='categorical_crossentropy')
autoencoder.fit(data, data,
                epochs=50,
                batch_size=1024)
```

I hope to start off the training at high EbNo_train and then gradually lower it with each epoch. Is it possible to change EbNo_train in each epoch?

Comment: Your question is written as such that I ge the notion you didn't try.. lets do that first and then if you hit an error report back by posting a new question on this topic.. or quickly try and modify your current question such that you include your new findings and error. Moved to editing.

Comment: Grammar, spacing